# Laravel 'where' collection method modifies the collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

Does the Laravel `where`**collection method** modify the collection?

On the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods) you can read this:

> almost every method returns a new Collection instance, allowing you to preserve the original copy of the collection

And the only methods which have a warning about modifying the collection are `transform`and `forget`

But I have this code:

```
    $descriptions = Description::where('description', $request->description);

    if ($descriptions->count()) {
        $descriptionsWithSameUnit = $descriptions->where('unit_id', $request->unit);
        if ($descriptionsWithSameUnit->count()==0) {
            $descriptionsWithAnotherUnit = $descriptions->where('unit_id', '!=', $request->unit);
            if ($descriptionsWithAnotherUnit->count()) {
        ...
```

And the collection IS modified after the first where so `$descriptionsWithAnotherUnit` is always empty, because on that point the collection only has the records where `unit_id == $request->unit`. Is this a bug in the framework or in the documentation?

And the question that arises from here: **What can I do to keep a copy of the original object without retrieving again from the DB?** I tried this:

```
$descriptions = Description::where('description', $request->description);

if ($descriptions->count()) {
    $descriptionsWithSameUnit = $descriptions;
    $descriptionsWithSameUnit->where('unit_id', $request->unit);
    ...
```

But the `$descriptions` object is also modified when I apply the `where` method to the `$descriptionsWithSameUnit` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that to get collection you need to use `get`, so if you want to get collection, you should do:

```
$descriptions = Description::where('description', $request->description)->get();
```

and not only:

```
$descriptions = Description::where('description', $request->description);
```

Second thing is that there's no possibility to use operator using [`where` method](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_where) on collection, so:

```
$descriptionsWithAnotherUnit = $descriptions->where('unit_id', '!=', $request->unit);
```

is completely incorrect. You should use `filter`method here.

Comment: Aaaahhh now I understand, I'm using the Eloquent where method, no the collection. Thks, I wasn't seeing that.

Comment: @MariaVilaró No problem. Those methods as you see are not the same as for Eloquent